# Is there any way to know the useParams from the top container?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm practicing nested routing using react-router-dom.

In Room001Container, there is a tab navigation bar that will be displayed on all components, and there is a button that navigates to a detailed post page when the button is pressed.

When I enter the room, I should see the post page first by default.
However, if I output postId as useParams in Room001Container component, undefined is returned.

In the PostDetail component, params are printed well, but why is it not output in the Room001Container? I know that the container is unconditionally rendered even if I move to each component, but it's really strange. Is there any way to know the params from the top container?

```js
function Container() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/channel/:channelId/lobby/:lobbyId"
        component={LobbyContainer}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}

function LobbyContainer() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
                exact
        path="/channel/:channelId/lobby/001"
        component={Room001Container}
      />
      <Route
                exact
        path="/channel/:channelId/lobby/002"
        component={Room002Container}
      />
      <Route
                exact
        path="/channel/:channelId/lobby/002"
        component={Room003Container}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}

function Room001Container() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { pathname } = history.location;

  const { channelId, postId } = useParams();

  console.log(postId) // undefined

  return (
    <>
      <S_TabBar>
        <Link to="/channel/:channelId/lobby/001/post">
          <S_TabCell>post</S_TabCell>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/channel/:channelId/lobby/001/chat">
          <S_TabCell>chat</S_TabCell>
        </Link>
      </S_TabBar>

            <S_Button onClick={() => history.push('/channel/:channelId/lobby/001/post/1')}>
                go to detail
            </S_Button>

      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/channel/:channelId/lobby/001/post"
          component={Post}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/channel/:channelId/lobby/001/post/:postId"
          component={PostDetail}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/channel/:channelId/lobby/001/chat"
          component={Chat}
        />
        <Redirect
          exact
          from="/channel/:channelId/lobby/001"
          to="/channel/:channelId/lobby/001/post"
        />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are using react-router-dom correctly. Shouldn't all routes be defined in one parent component and then depending on that we display some data from components?

Answer (score 0):

There is no postId parameter in the route that mounts Room001Container.

You'll want e. g.

```
<Route
        exact
        path="/channel/:channelId/lobby/:postId"
        component={Room001Container}
/>
```